# Calling an SSIS task from C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, ssis, visual-studio-2017

This appears to be a re-hash of an old problem.  There are several other posts on this, but the solutions suggest using DTS or other assemblies that are depreciated. My problem most likely has nothing to do with SSIS and more to do with adding assembly references though:

I am following step by step instructions from the [Microsoft Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-dotnet?view=sql-server-2017), but first of all when I open the Reference Manager and expand Assemblies/Extensions, the following two extensions do not show up:

- Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo

Actually nothing shows up: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Xty.png)

I actually found them in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\SDK\Assemblies so I included from there and moved on.

My problem comes in the next step, when I add
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices

Visual Studio tells me that the type or namespace does not exist and asks if I'm missing an assembly reference.  I also see the little yellow warning triangles on top of the assembly references, but I cannot figure out how to tell what they mean.  Hoping this is something dumb that I'm overlooking but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just have to ask... SSDT is installed with Integration Services, yes?

Comment: yeah.  updated w/ all latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suggestion that is a different direction altogether, and that is starting the SSIS packages with stored procedures. Then, in your C# code you are only executing  stored procedures, which is trivial.

First, you create an execution using the stored procedure SSISDB.catalog.create_execution, and your SQL will look something like this:

```
EXEC   SSISDB.catalog.create_execution
         @folder_name = N'myFolder',
         @project_name = @proj_name,
         @package_name = @myPackage,
         @reference_id = @ref_id,
         @use32bitruntime = 0,
         @execution_id = @ex_id OUTPUT;
```

Next, set your parameters if you have any using SSISDB.catalog.set_execution_parameter_value. The SQL will look something like this:

```
EXEC SSISDB.catalog.set_execution_parameter_value @ex_id, 20, N'Acq_Event_Id', @ACQ_EVENT_ID;
--Set CUSTOMIZED_LOGGING_LEVEL to the name of the   custom log level for this execution
EXEC SSISDB.catalog.set_execution_parameter_value @ex_id, 50, N'LOGGING_LEVEL', 100;
EXEC SSISDB.catalog.set_execution_parameter_value @ex_id, 50, N'CUSTOMIZED_LOGGING_LEVEL', N'ETL_Logging';
```

Lastly, you start the execution using SSISDB.catalog.start_execution. You pass to it the execution ID that was created and passed back to you when you executed the first stored proc. This step looks like this:

```
EXEC SSISDB.catalog.start_execution @ex_id;
```

Comment: I thought of this too.  This was actually going to be my next course of action, but after about 7 hours of googling and trying different things, rebooting my computer ended up solving the problem.  I ended up testing the sproc method as well and it definitely did work, requires fewer assembly references, and is fewer lines of code.